# GSON - use unicode characters

Tags: java, json, utf-8, gson

In my GSON testing class I have a class with a string that has to be serialized.

The problem is, that special unicode characters like the `\u06A4` or the `►` are converted to `?`. That is not how I want this to work.

Here's my class:

```
public final class JSONvsBinary {

    public static final void run() throws Exception {

        A a1 = new A();
        a1.a = "bla, blu., € @ xyz Ø, \u06A4 ►";

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT);
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        builder.disableHtmlEscaping();
        builder.serializeNulls();
        builder.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues();
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        final String gsonString = gson.toJson(a1, A.class);
        final byte[] gsonBytes = gsonString.getBytes("UTF8");
        System.out.println("GSON:\n" + new String(gsonBytes, "UTF8"));
        System.out.println("GSON bytes: " + gsonBytes.length);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final class A {

        public String a;

    }

}
```

And that's the output:

```
GSON:
{
  "a": "bla, blu., € @ xyz Ø, ? ?"
}
GSON bytes: 44
```

I set the byte encoding to UTF-8 but it doesn't work...

Comment: Honestly, this has nothing to do with Gson - your terminal isn't displaying those characters correctly. Works perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: Oh, interesting. How can I display these messages? Using JOptionPanes?

Comment: What is the default character set on your system? Seems odd that it's *not* utf-8. Unless ... is this windows and you're using the command line? It's prob windows-1252 which would explain it. If so, yes ... or use an IDE with a console window.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. It's from the eclipse console view.

Comment: I don't use eclipse or an OS that's not UTF-8 by default, so I'm not the expert, but it looks like you can specify: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

Comment: And I don't know that it would matter, but you're using the current 2.2.4 of gson, yes? It's what I tested against.

Comment: I'm using 2.2.4. But I just tested it using a JOptionPane. You were right. It was just a problem of displaying.

Answer (score 4):

One, make sure your compiler and editor are [using the same encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles). This is usually not an issue in an IDE.

The problem is probably here: `System.out.println`.

From the [documentation for PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html):

> All characters printed by a `PrintStream` are converted into bytes using the platform's default character encoding.

So, depending on [the platform encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29), `System.out` can lose data.

On top of this, the rendering engine of the device `System.out` is sending data to must support a grapheme for rendering each code point in the character data.